# finding all interval containments

Tags: java, algorithm, intervals, information-extraction

Given a set of intervals (integer pairs representing a range) I would like to find all interval containment relationships. The application I'm using it for is removing redundant items in an information extraction system; given a collection of extracted segments, some categorized as addresses, if I detect that intervals [2,3] and [2,6] are both addresses (maybe the first is the street address but the second contains everything until the zip code), then I only need the containing interval.

I could only find a few mentions of this problem online, and I used the sparse notes [here](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs5114/spring2014/notes0130.pdf) to implement the following in Java:

```
import static java.util.Collections.reverseOrder;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class IntervalContainmentDetector {
    private static class Interval {
        private final int left;
        private final int right;
        public Interval(int l, int r) {
            left = l;
            right = r;
        }
        public int getLeft() {
            return left;
        }
        public int getRight() {
            return right;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "[" + left + "," + right + "]";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        List<Interval> intervals = new LinkedList<Interval>() {
            {
                add(new Interval(0, 4));
                add(new Interval(2, 3));
                add(new Interval(0, 6));
                add(new Interval(4, 9));
                add(new Interval(4, 9));
                add(new Interval(4, 5));
                add(new Interval(3, 4));
                add(new Interval(6, 9));
                add(new Interval(4, 4));
                add(new Interval(5, 7));
                add(new Interval(1, 2));
            }
        };

        findContainments(intervals);
    }

    // sort ascending on left, descending on right;
    private static final Comparator<Interval> INTERVAL_SORTER = Comparator
            .comparing(Interval::getLeft).thenComparing(
                    interval -> interval.getRight(), reverseOrder());

    private static void findContainments(List<Interval> intervals) {
        List<Interval> sorted = intervals.stream().sorted(INTERVAL_SORTER)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("sorted: " + sorted);
        while (!sorted.isEmpty()) {
            LinkedList<Interval> containers = new LinkedList<>();
            containers.add(sorted.remove(0));
            recurse(sorted, containers);
        }
    }

    private static void recurse(List<Interval> remainingList,
            LinkedList<Interval> inList) {
        if (remainingList.isEmpty())
            return;
        while (!remainingList.isEmpty()) {
            Interval thisElement = remainingList.get(0);
            if (thisElement.getRight() <= inList.getLast().getRight()) {
                printContainment(inList, thisElement);
                remainingList.remove(0);
                inList.addLast(thisElement);
                recurse(remainingList, inList);
                inList.removeLast();
            } else
                return;
        }
    }

    private static void printContainment(List<Interval> containerList,
            Interval containedElement) {
        System.out.println(containedElement + " is contained by "
                + containerList);
    }
}
```

The "sorted" print is to determine that the sort is working correctly. The above code prints the following:

```
sorted: [[0,6], [0,4], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,9], [4,9], [4,5], [4,4], [5,7], [6,9]]
[0,4] is contained by [[0,6]]
[1,2] is contained by [[0,6], [0,4]]
[2,3] is contained by [[0,6], [0,4]]
[3,4] is contained by [[0,6], [0,4]]
[4,9] is contained by [[4,9]]
[4,5] is contained by [[4,9], [4,9]]
[4,4] is contained by [[4,9], [4,9], [4,5]]
[5,7] is contained by [[4,9], [4,9]]
[6,9] is contained by [[4,9], [4,9]]
```

It misses that [4,5] is contained by [0,6]; if I remove the two [4,9] pairs then the algorithm works correctly.

I'm not sure how to update the algorithm to work correctly for this case (where a non-contained interval contains a contained interval, effectively blocking the relationship from being discovered). I realize now that the statement of the problem I see in the slides I mentioned above (and on this [other class site](http://staff.cs.upt.ro/~ioana/algo/lab_designindu.html)) is to list the intervals that are contained inside any other interval, not to list all containment relationships.

How can I update this algorithm to correctly find all interval containments?

Comment: There are O(n^2) possible interval containments (just consider n copies of the same interval -- or if strict containment is required, then consider n intervals of the form [i, 2n-i+1], for i from 1 to n: each interval contains every later interval).  So if you want to list them all, you need a worst-case O(n^2) algorithm.  So you might as well just use a simple pair of nested `for` loops.

Comment: To speed up the nested-pair-of-`for`-loops: First sort by start position, and split the innermost (j) loop in two: one loop works backwards from the current (i-th) interval; a second loop works forwards from the i-th.  You can exit the first innermost loop as soon as `x[j].getLeft() < x[i].getLeft()`, and the second as soon as `x[j].getLeft() > x[i].getRight()`.  This may be similar to what your code is already (buggily) doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found time to read up youre base for the algorithm. This is a true O(n*log(n)) one. However, it is just trying to identify that the current interval is contained in any previous one ("...is contained in some other interval.").

What you are trying is different. You intend to list all containment relations. 
This is not covered by the original algorithm and this is what kills the log(n) reduction and leads to O(n^2) complexity.

You will recognize the notes on the algorithm just keeps track of "the righmost endpoint" encountered. No tracking of earlier intervals.

This reduction in goal is what makes an algorith with reduced complexity possible in the first place.

Getting **all** containments is forcing you to process the partial ordering of intervals. (This is what causes your algorithm to fail detecting some containments.) The original algorithm exploits a transformation to a total ordering of the intervals for getting "some containment" property.

For exact containment you need to obey the natural partial ordering, ending up to do full n*(n-1) comparisons.
Alternatively you may exploit knowledge about the relations among the intervals to be checked, but this contradicts the need to run the algorithm in the first place.
So I doubt you will get better than O(n^2) for getting all containments.

Comment: Thanks. I will reduce my problem by grouping extracted segments by their category and running the algorithm on each one. That way I can simply remove any contained segments (address in an address, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Map<Interval, List<Interval>> mapContainments = new HashMap<>();

for(Interval interval : listIntervals) {
    List<Interval> containments = listIntervals.stream()
        .filter(i -> i != interval 
             && i.getLeft() <= interval.getLeft() 
             && i.getRight() >= interval.getRight())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    mapContainments.put(interval, containments);
}
```

`mapContainers` will contain all the containments for each interval.

Comment: I think this is the brute-force n^2 time approach. I'd like a more efficient n*log(n) approach if possible, which is why I was implementing it the way I did. That said, since my problem statement is different than what I found online, I'm not sure it's possible (but hoping it is).

Comment: @Nate Glenn: what qualifies the original algorithm as n*log(n)? It loops over n elements checking the remaining (n-1) ones. It just exploits the statistical chance of not all following elements being contained. E.g. consider [0,100],[1,100],[2,100], etc. as an input case.

Comment: @rpy If it's not n*log(n) then I did it wrong, as that was what I was going for based on the lecture notes I pointed to. The initial sort is n*log(n), and after that another n for processing each item in `remainingList` once. If all n-1 elements were actually checked for one item then that would be the end of all processing.